# Steps needed for integration to box api into web application

Tags: asp.net, oauth, box-api, box

Something similar to what whatsapp does and saves user's chat; but I want it with files.
Please provide me with any kind of help like steps or any other form of help which would help me achieve this.
A few other questions: How to connect user and which URL should I hit to connect the user and get user's API key so that user's files can be accessed. 
How do I get the login modal to open and get the API key?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this use case:

**Option 1: Box File Picker**

The [Box File Picker](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/the-box-file-picker) lets your users share their Box content with your application without using OAuth.

**Option 2: Box Content API**

The [Box Content API](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/get-started-with-the-box-api) lets your users authorize your application to read/write data in their Box account. This integration uses OAuth. After the authentication process, you can read/write a user data in Box using a REST API.

Comment: Option 1: Box File Picker

The Box File Picker lets your users share their Box content with your application without using OAuth.


Using this option can I download there files.